# How can i add where condition in firebase query based on if condition?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I am writing a query in firebase, but I want to add `where()` condition based on the condition. Like if some values are exist then `where()` should be included otherwise normal query should be run as it is. Below is my code. I checked using `console.log` if condition is passed but the query returns all results. Please help me to fix this issue.

```
const loadPapers = () => {
  let t = savedTopifyPapers
  if (queryParams.value.key && queryParams.value.value) {
    t.orderBy('timeStamp')
      .limit(limit.value)
      .where(queryParams.value.key.toString(), '==', queryParams.value.value)
  } else {
    t.orderBy('timeStamp').limit(limit.value)
  }
  t.onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
    const _lastDoc = snapshot.docs[snapshot.docs.length - 1]
    firstVisible.value = snapshot.docs[0]
    if (_lastDoc) {
      lastDoc.value = _lastDoc
    }
    if (snapshot.empty) {
      loadingData.value = false
    }
    papersData.value = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => {
      const data = doc.data()
      const id = doc.id
      loadingData.value = false
      return { id, ...data }
    })
    papersDataLength.value = papersData.value.length
  })
}
```

Any solution appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just take reference of `collection`.
 `let query = firebase.firestore().collection(collectionName)`.

```
query = query.where(...)
query = query.where(...)
```

and with use of condition

```
if (condition) {
  query = query.where(...)
}
```

execute query after all clause add.

```
query.get().then(...)
```

Comment: I am doing the same, but it is not working. `let t = savedTopifyPapers` this is the collection reference

Comment: Ohh i understand you mean i have to add every single line to same variable again.

Comment: yes you have to add each query ref to `query` variable